# Images not loading when JavaScriptEnabled in android webview

Tags: android, xamarin

I have a android web view

```
webview = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView);
```

I load the htmlData from the url like so:

```
 webview.LoadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", htmlData, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

The content includes text, images and embedded youtube videos.

In the case above the text and images load correctly but not the videos as i have not enabled Javascript yet.

Therefore i enable JavaScriptEnabled.

```
  webview.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
  webview.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;//This does not make any difference
```

However, when i do enable Javascript the images no longer load within my webview but the videos do.

After debugging, I can see that the entire image tag is being replaced with `&nbsp`

So i would like to know how to have javascript enabled and have my images still load within my htmldata at the same time.

Comment: Is there any JavaScript error message? You can output the console message like this: https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/debugging.html

Comment: Thanks, i do get "Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 12142". Which apparently should be solved by setting DomStorageEnabled=true

Comment: Actually it always prints the message regardless if JS enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I guess JavaScript may change the src attribete of img tag.

You can do RemoteDebug of webview. Let's check the html dom.

developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/…

Comment: Thanks very helpful link, I can now see the images are replaced with &nbsp; when JS is enabled.

Comment: There was a <noscript> tag which was changing the value when js was enabled. Fixed!